# How to change the password together with the user's user change?

Tags: angular

I have this form to change the user. And when I change the user data, the login and email changed, and the password is not updated.

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Login<label style="color:#DD0330;">*</label>:</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='selectedUser.login' class="form-control border-input" name="login" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">E-mail<label style="color:#DD0330;">*</label>:</label>
        <input type="email" [(ngModel)]='selectedUser.email' class="form-control border-input" name="email" required>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group form-black">
         <label class="control-label">Password<label>&nbsp;</label></label>
         <input type="password" class="form-control border-input"  [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.password" name="password">
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group form-black">
         <label class="control-label">Password Confirmation<label>&nbsp;</label></label>
         <input type="password" class="form-control border-input"  [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </form>
 <div class="col-md-6">
   <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right"  (click)="saveUser(users)">Save</button>
 </div>
```

What did I do wrong? If you need to add something else, please report.

```
  saveUser(users: User) {
    this.servUser.updateUser(this.selectedUser).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.loadUsers();
      }, 
       error => {
         console.log(error);
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Can you create a working example for this?(in stackblitz)

Comment: I have creared the demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnpexn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts here hope this will help you

Comment: @AniketAvhad Did not help, the password for some reason does not change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right"  (click)="saveUser()">Save</button>
 </div>
```

and then in your component

```
public selectedUser=new User();

     saveUser() {
        this.servUser.updateUser(this.selectedUser).subscribe(
          data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.loadUsers();
          }, 
           error => {
             console.log(error);
          }
        )
      }
```

Comment: Did not help, the password for some reason does not change

Comment: All, thank you, I found where the error is, it's not related to the Angular)